# install White error using Nuget in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I try to install [white](https://github.com/TestStack/White) in VS 2015, using the command

```
Install-Package TestStack.White
```

But it always show the error message below:
[image]

I already tried following to fix the problem, but can not work:

1) uninstall the visual studio, and reinstall

2) remove the nuget and install again

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone has idea of how to fixing this problem?

**You should use this command with a solution is open in Visual Studio 2015.** Just as the error message mention that “*Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.*”, If you do not have a project that is open, nuget does not know where to install the package.

You can check my test results below, the first installation without a solution open, then second installation with TestStackWhite solution open:

[image]

Hope this can help you.